# Does the suggestion that people were fighting over the food at "the Lord's supper" in 1 Corinthians 11:21 indicate that it was an actual meal?

Tags: 1-corinthians

> KJV 1 Corinthians 11:21 For in eating every one taketh before other his
>   own supper: and one is hungry, and another is drunken.
>
> KJV 1 Corinthians 11:34 And if any man hunger, let him eat at home;
>   that ye come not together unto condemnation. And the rest will I set
>   in order when I come.

In other words, this was not a wafer and cuplet situation but rather a sit-down dinner, yes?

Comment: _When ye come together therefore into one place, this is not to eat the Lord's supper._ I Corinthians 11:20. Yes, they were evidently eating a meal. No, this is _not_ the Lord's supper (says Paul). Paul corrects what they were doing, because they were doing it wrong.

Comment: So on the night when Jesus was betrayed he and the disciples had just Pita bread and Manichewitz wine for their meal? Paul says they supped:  
1 Cor 11:23 "After the same manner also he took the cup, *when he had supped*, saying, This cup is the new testament in my blood: this do ye, as oft as ye drink it, in remembrance of me."  Or are you saying that Jesus and the disciples ate a meal, the disciples ate a meal but fought over it so the fix was to eliminate the food?

Comment: What they ate was the passover lamb. Then, afterwards (after that partaking) Jesus took bread and broke it and passed it around. Likewise the cup. It was the institution of another ceremony - a memorial of his flesh and his blood given in sacrifice. There is no wording - anywhere - regarding 'fighting over food'.

Answer (score 2):

In 1Cor 11:17-19, Paul criticizes the Corinthians for acting like high schoolers by forming cliques, eating too much, and getting *drunk*.

- That some people were eating too much is implied when he mentions that "one is hungry". Ever been last in line at a potluck only to find that all the food is gone?
- There probably weren't any 'food fights', or outright 'fighting' over food, but they were likely cutting in line ("taketh before other his own supper"). It isn't too different from how some people behave today.

> *So then,* when you come together, it is not the Lord’s Supper you eat, – 1Cor 11:20 (NIV)

The phrase "so then" refers back to his earlier criticism. It's implied that they're *supposed* to be eating the Lord's Supper, but they aren't *because of their behavior*.

Many religions conclude worship with a substantial meal. Sacrificial animals were cooked (as burnt offerings) and served in meals, which Paul describes in 1Cor 8 and 10. It's likely the early church followed similar practices, and the Lord's Supper *did* consist of a *real* meal. Although no longer considered part of the Lord's Supper, some modern churches *do* have potlucks.

Paul describes the ritual in verses 23-26 to remind the Corinthians that their behavior is antithetical to remembering Lord Jesus. *Not* to tell them to replace the meal with a wafer and sip of wine.

> So then, whoever eats the bread or drinks the cup of the Lord in an unworthy manner will be guilty of sinning against the body and blood of the Lord. – 1Cor 11:27 (NIV)

He ends by telling them to get their act together. Stop falling asleep in church, and be more disciplined. (28-32) And eat together as a church, not in your own little groups (that's *why* it's called *communion*). (33) And eat breakfast before coming to church, so you won't cut in line, causing others to "judge" (34) (because you already know the sermon is going to be long – that's why you fell asleep while I was still talking).